# dplyr::mutate gives x/y = NA, summarise gives x/y = real number

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm working on validating a function to calculate pass rates for a certain criterion in my lab.  The mathematics behind this are very simple: Given a number of tests that either passed or failed, what percentage passed.

The data will be provided as a column of values that are either `P1` (passed on first test), `F1` (failed on first test), `P2` or `F2` (passed or failed on second test, respectively).  I wrote the function `passRate` below to assist in calculating the pass rates overall (first and second try) and on the first test and second test in isolation.

The quality specialist who set up the parameters for the validation gave me a list of pass and fail counts that I am converting into a vector using the `test_vector` function below.

Everything was looking great until I got to the third row of the `Pass` data frame, which contains the pass/fail counts from my quality specialist.  Instead of returning a second test pass rate of 100%, it returns NA...but only when I use `mutate`

```
library(dplyr)

Pass <- structure(list(P1 = c(2L, 0L, 10L), 
                       F1 = c(0L, 2L, 0L), 
                       P2 = c(0L, 3L, 2L), 
                       F2 = c(0L, 2L, 0L), 
                       id = 1:3), 
                  .Names = c("P1", "F1", "P2", "F2", "id"), 
                  class = c("tbl_df", "data.frame"), 
                  row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

So here's something akin to what I did with `mutate`.

```
Pass %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(pass_rate = (P1 + P2) / (P1 + P2 + F1 + F2) * 100,
         pass_rate1 = P1 / (P1 + F1) * 100,
         pass_rate2 = P2 / (P2 + F2) * 100)

Source: local data frame [3 x 8]
Groups: id [3]

     P1    F1    P2    F2    id pass_rate pass_rate1 pass_rate2
  (int) (int) (int) (int) (int)     (dbl)      (dbl)      (dbl)
1     2     0     0     0     1 100.00000        100         NA
2     0     2     3     2     2  42.85714          0         60
3    10     0     3     1     3 100.00000        100         NA
```

Compare when I use `summarise`

```
Pass %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(pass_rate = (P1 + P2) / (P1 + P2 + F1 + F2) * 100,
            pass_rate1 = P1 / (P1 + F1) * 100,
            pass_rate2 = P2 / (P2 + F2) * 100)

Source: local data frame [3 x 4]

     id pass_rate pass_rate1 pass_rate2
  (int)     (dbl)      (dbl)      (dbl)
1     1 100.00000        100         NA
2     2  42.85714          0         60
3     3 100.00000        100        100
```

I would have expected these to return the same results.  My guess is that `mutate` is having problems somewhere because it assumes `n` rows per group should map to `n` rows in the result (is it getting confused in calculating `n` here?), while `summarise` knows that no matter how many rows it starts with, it's going to end with just 1.

Does anyone have any thoughts on what the mechanics behind this behavior are?

Comment: That is a really convoluted example. Do you have a simpler one that illustrates what sounds like a bug (in your title)? Here's the typical reference: [mcve]

Comment: You're right, I hadn't spent much time trying to de-convolute it.  I've put in code to directly calculate the results without all the extra functions.

Comment: Seems like a bug : `Pass <- data.frame(P2 = c(0,3,2), F2 = c(0,2,0), id = 1:3); Pass %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(pass2 = P2/(P2 + F2))`. There shouldn't be any NA in row 3

Comment: Possibly the same bug as [here](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/1448)

Comment: And, like the question referenced in that issue, I think it's fair to say that I was probably trying to do too much with `mutate` (at least in my initial convoluted example) and should have approached it with a combination of `do` and `summarise`, because as it turns out, in the simplified example, if you take out the `group_by` and go straight to `mutate`, you get the expected result.  So perhaps this is just a case of group abuse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me like some interference between `dplyr` and `plyr`. I had the same issue with another unbalanced dataset (so grouping was necessary), where exactly in the **third** group the mutated variable was erroneously NA! Then I reproduced your example at home. First, after

```
library("dplyr", lib.loc="~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2")
```

I got exactly your results. Then I executed my own script, where the package `plyr` had been loaded. After the warning not to load `plyr` after `dplyr`, the NA in my **third** group was gone and also your example was computed correctly! Here is what I did (I added one more row to see if NA remains in the third group):

```
> Pass <- structure(list(P1 = c(2L, 0L, 10L,8L), 
+                        F1 = c(0L, 2L, 0L, 4L), 
+                        P2 = c(0L, 3L, 2L, 2L), 
+                        F2 = c(0L, 2L, 0L, 1L), 
+                        id = 1:4), 
+                   .Names = c("P1", "F1", "P2", "F2", "id"), 
+                   class = c("tbl_df", "data.frame"), 
+                   row.names = c(NA, -4L))
> Pass %>%
+     group_by(id) %>%
+     mutate(pass_rate = (P1 + P2) / (P1 + P2 + F1 + F2) * 100,
+            pass_rate1 = P1 / (P1 + F1) * 100,
+            pass_rate2 = P2 / (P2 + F2) * 100)
Source: local data frame [4 x 8]
Groups: id [4]

 P1    F1    P2    F2    id pass_rate pass_rate1 pass_rate2
(int) (int) (int) (int) (int)     (dbl)      (dbl)      (dbl)
 1     2     0     0     0     1 100.00000  100.00000         NA
 2     0     2     3     2     2  42.85714    0.00000   60.00000
 3    10     0     2     0     3 100.00000  100.00000         NA
 4     8     4     2     1     4  66.66667   66.66667   66.66667
```

Then I did:

```
> library("plyr", lib.loc="~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2")
> Pass %>%
+     group_by(id) %>%
+     mutate(pass_rate = (P1 + P2) / (P1 + P2 + F1 + F2) * 100,
+            pass_rate1 = P1 / (P1 + F1) * 100,
+            pass_rate2 = P2 / (P2 + F2) * 100)
Source: local data frame [4 x 8]
Groups: id [4]

 P1    F1    P2    F2    id pass_rate pass_rate1 pass_rate2
(int) (int) (int) (int) (int)     (dbl)      (dbl)      (dbl)
 1     2     0     0     0     1 100.00000  100.00000        NaN
 2     0     2     3     2     2  42.85714    0.00000   60.00000
 3    10     0     2     0     3 100.00000  100.00000  100.00000
 4     8     4     2     1     4  66.66667   66.66667   66.66667
```

I know that it is not a satisfying answer because `plyr` should **NOT** be loaded after `dplyr`, but maybe it helps those out who need to `group_by(id)`. Or use `plyr::mutate()`. Then you can load `dplyr` after `plyr`:

```
 > Pass %>%
+     group_by(id) %>%
+     plyr::mutate(pass_rate = (P1 + P2) / (P1 + P2 + F1 + F2) * 100,
+            pass_rate1 = P1 / (P1 + F1) * 100,
+            pass_rate2 = P2 / (P2 + F2) * 100)
Source: local data frame [4 x 8]
Groups: id [4]

 P1    F1    P2    F2    id pass_rate pass_rate1 pass_rate2
(int) (int) (int) (int) (int)     (dbl)      (dbl)      (dbl)
 1     2     0     0     0     1 100.00000  100.00000        NaN
 2     0     2     3     2     2  42.85714    0.00000   60.00000
 3    10     0     2     0     3 100.00000  100.00000  100.00000
 4     8     4     2     1     4  66.66667   66.66667   66.66667
```

Comment: There is something I never would have thought of. Fascinating side effect.

Comment: I think this is mostly due to `group_by` not working after loading `plyr`.